# Pattern for multiple methods with same implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns

*What design pattern can be used when you have multiple classes with the same methods and implementation?*

I thought about using the Facade pattern which provides acces to methods. But when I look at the class diagram it is not exactly what I want.

Another idea was to use an (abstract) class which implemented these methods and the classes will extend this (abstract) class.

The next method is defined in six different classes. There are multiple methods like this and it becomes difficult to maintain.

```
private void FactoryFaulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChannelFactory factory = (ChannelFactory)sender;

        try
        {
            factory.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            factory.Abort();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make your example broader? Why would you need the same implementation over and over? How about generics? How about moving the common stuff into a separate object which will work on multiple different "data" objects? Due to testing concerns, i would not use a base class.

Comment: Having the method in a base class would seem the obvious solution as long as it was logical for these classes to share a base class...

Comment: So, basically copies of a method scattered over different classes? It's not a GoF pattern, but have you thought about factoring the method into a separate class which is used by your existing classes? This would be composition as opposed to a common base class...

Comment: Without seeing whole picture its hard to give good advice. If all duplicated methods are exactly same, then moving them all up in hierarchy is good option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the abstract class and extend this, or create a Helper class, and call in all classes like this:

```
public static Helper
{
    public static void FactoryFaulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChannelFactory factory = (ChannelFactory)sender;

        try
        {
            factory.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            factory.Abort();
        }
    }
}

public class YourClass
{
   public void DoSomething()
   {
       var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory();
       Helper.FactoryFaulted(channelFactory, null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use a Helper class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the way that you deal with identical code is different from the way in which you deal with similar code. Design patterns, such as the [*Template Method Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), are helpful in reducing the amount of code that is similar among many classes, but not identical.

When the code is identical, you can put it in a static function, and reuse as-is:

```
internal static class FactoryHelper {
    // Note that your method is not using instance variables of the class,
    // making it an ideal candidate for making a static helper method.
    public static void FactoryFaulted(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChannelFactory factory = (ChannelFactory)sender;
        try {
            factory.Close();
        } catch {
            factory.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```